# Permission required for deploy a dacpac

Tags: sql, deployment

I am trying to deploy a dacpac on tenant using sqlpackage.exe.
Currently I am giving SysAdmin or db_owner permission to the account which will deploy this and it works fine.
But in production, if the target tenant database is of some other application, I might not get these permissions, so would like to know the minimal permission that is required for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here: [Upgrade a Data-tier Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634742.aspx#Permissions)

> Permissions
>
> A DAC can only be upgraded by members of the sysadmin or serveradmin fixed server roles, or by logins that are in the dbcreator fixed server role and have ALTER ANY LOGIN permissions. The login must be the owner of the existing database. The built-in SQL Server system administrator account named sa can also upgrade a DAC.

Answer (score 0):

To update an existing database, you may need to disable the "Deploy database properties" advanced option if deploying in Visual Studio or "/p:ScriptDatabaseOptions=False" when deploying using SQLPACKAGE.EXE.

Answer (score 0):

It may be difficult to find someone who'll give you sysadmin or serveradmin on your production DB server. If this is the case, consider using SqlPackage to [generate scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37557599/1585345), comparing your DACPAC to the production schema, then run the scripts (requiring only dbowner). These two lines of powershell will do it for you...

```
SqlPackage /Action:"Script" /SourceFile:"path_to_my.dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"my connection string" /p:"BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False" /OutputPath:"c:\someFolder\DBDiff.sql"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString "my connection string" -InputFile "c:\someFolder\DBDiff.sql" -OutputSqlErrors $true
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. In my case, the pipeline succeeded only by providing the `db_owner` role on the Production database.

Comment: The first part of your answer seems interesting, the second one should be deleted. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: I edited this to be an answer to the question. Please post the follow-up question as a new question.

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow is *** *** ***not*** *** *** *** a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)