# What is "DacInstance with the specified instance_id does not exist. (Microsoft SQL Server, 36004)"?

Tags: sql-server, dacpac

I'm trying to upgrade a remote SQL Server 2012 database using a dacpac, but I'm getting the following message: **DacInstance with the specified instance_id does not exist. (Microsoft SQL Server, 36004)**. I tried to search on the internet but couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I just encountered this problem myself. I hunted through the User Mapping for my login, adding db_owner, db_securityadmin role memberships for all relevant databases. No help.

Specifically, it was necessary to add the "sysadmin" server role to the user. After doing this, my dacpacs were able to deploy successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is an permission issue. The user has to have administrative privileges to update the database using a dacpac.

Comment: Where did you find this and what exactly are administrative previledges? And do not hesitate to go ahead if your own answer answers your qurstion and mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The exactly required permissions are descripted here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/upgrade-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver15#Permissions

> A DAC can only be upgraded by members of the sysadmin or serveradmin fixed server roles, or by logins that are in the dbcreator fixed server role and have ALTER ANY LOGIN permissions. The login must be the owner of the existing database. The built-in SQL Server system administrator account named sa can also upgrade a DAC.

(found in question https://stackoverflow.com/a/16452329/13467853)