# Deploying on OctoPack Error

Tags: powershell, deployment, sql-server-2014, dacpac, octopack

I'm using a tutorial to deploy a dacpac through OctoPack.

http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/deploy-a-database-project-dacpac-using-octopusdeploy-and-powershell/

I'm getting an error saying the following:

Exception calling "Deploy" with "5" argument(s): "DacInstance with the specified instance_id does not exist."
At Deploy.ps1
+ $d.Deploy <<<< ($dp, $dbName, $TRUE, $dacProfile.DeployOptions)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Has anyone else faced this issue? What's causing it? It says there's 5 arguments but I'm only counting 4, and none of them are instance_id.

Comment: Could be permissions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202844/what-is-dacinstance-with-the-specified-instance-id-does-not-exist-microsoft-s

Comment: The `DacServices.Deploy` method does indeed have 5 arguments, [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacservices.deploy(v=sql.120).aspx).  The 3rd, 4th, and 5th parameters have default values and are thus optional.  The tutorial is omitting the last parameter `cancellationToken`, allowing it to take its default value of `$null`.

Answer (score 0):

From experience I can tell that the *Octopus Deploy Community Step Template* [**SQL - Deploy DACPAC**](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-templates/58399364-4367-41d5-ad35-c2c6a8258536/actiontemplate-sql-deploy-dacpac) works very well. No need to write PowerShell scripts. Add this Step Template to Octopus, add it to your project, fill in the variables and off you go.