# Can I generate a deployment script from a dacpac

Tags: sql, msbuild, publish, dacpac

I've got a .dacpac file that's being called by MSBuild and published to a QA database for testing. This publish is failing and the error I'm getting back from them is a generic "an error has occurred" message. I was hoping I could generate the deployment script from the dacpac and walk through it to see where the  problem is occurring and hopefully teach them how to do this as well.

Is there any way to point a dacpac at a specific database and have it generate the sql for updating the database without actually publishing to the database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx).  Look for it on your machine in a directory with a name similar to this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin

Note that it may be found in the `110`, `120` or `130` folder.

If you don't have `SqlPackage.exe` already, you can download it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53013

If you download it, **be sure to look in the System Requirements section** of the download page to find the dependencies `SqlSysClrTypes.msi` and `SqlDom.msi`, which must be installed as well.

Example usage:

> SqlPackage.exe /a:script /SourceFile:C:\temp\mydb.dacpac /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=true" /OutputPath:C:\temp

Comment: FYI: the above reference is for an outdated version of `SqlPackage.exe` here is the current latest:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53013