# Azure DevOps - Changes are not deploying on PROD for Azure SQL Database even though release pipeline is getting succeeded

Tags: sql, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, dacpac

I'm setting up an Azure DevOps for Azure SQL Database by deploying the SQL DacPac file through Release pipeline. I'm promoting changes from DEV to PROD database.

I'm new to the Azure DevOps did all the setup through Azure documentation and google, got stuck at this point.

Build pipeline and release pipeline are getting succeeded but the changes are not reflecting in PROD database.
**Please find below the YAML of release pipeline:**

```
steps:
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Azure SQL DacpacTask'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'azure_subscription'
    ServerName: server_name
    DatabaseName: 'database_name'
    SqlUsername: user_name
    SqlPassword: password
    DeploymentAction: DeployReport
    DacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureDB_Test/Test/bin/Debug/Test.dacpac'
```

**Please find below the logs of Azure SQL DacPacTask :**

```
2024-01-06T21:27:27.9410537Z ##[section]Starting: Azure SQL DacpacTask
2024-01-06T21:27:27.9722384Z ==============================================================================
2024-01-06T21:27:27.9722835Z Task         : Azure SQL Database deployment
2024-01-06T21:27:27.9723374Z Description  : Deploy an Azure SQL Database using DACPAC or run scripts using SQLCMD
2024-01-06T21:27:27.9723284Z Version      : 1.232.0
2024-01-06T21:27:27.9723394Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-01-06T21:27:27.9723957Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment
2024-01-06T21:27:27.9723395Z ==============================================================================
2024-01-06T21:27:29.7550294Z Added TLS 1.2 in session.
2024-01-06T21:27:44.6571057Z Temporary inline SQL file: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC89E.tmp
2024-01-06T21:27:44.9123856Z Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "server_name" -Database "database_name" -Username "user_name"  -Password "password"  -Inputfile "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC89E.tmp"  **-ConnectionTimeout 120**
2024-01-06T21:27:58.3224482Z DACPAC file path: D:\a\r1\a\_nEDS_AzureDB_Test\nEDS_Test\bin\Debug\nEDS_Test.dacpac
2024-01-06T21:27:58.6926284Z ##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\SqlAzureDacpacDeployment_ch87a08b-a478-4e2b-8369-1d37u9ab560f\1.232.0\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,18.0) -latest -format json
2024-01-06T21:27:59.5484384Z "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:DeployReport /SourceFile:"D:\a\r1\a\AzureDB_Test\Test\bin\Debug\Test.dacpac" /TargetServerName:"server_name" /TargetDatabaseName:"database_name" /TargetUser:"user_name" /TargetPassword:"password" /OutputPath:"D:\a\r1\a\GeneratedOutputFiles\ACAEDS_Prod_DevOps_DeployReport.xml"  /**TargetTimeout:120**
2024-01-06T21:28:04.0578492Z Generating report for database 'database_name' on server 'server_name'.
2024-01-06T21:28:23.7792056Z Successfully generated report to file D:\a\r1\a\GeneratedOutputFiles\Report.xml.
2024-01-06T21:28:23.7803000Z Changes to connection setting default values were incorporated in a recent release.  More information is available at https://aka.ms/dacfx-connection
2024-01-06T21:28:23.7806733Z Time elapsed 0:00:20.21
2024-01-06T21:28:23.8142166Z Generated file D:\a\r1\a\GeneratedOutputFiles\Report.xml. Uploading file to the logs.
2024-01-06T21:28:23.8160223Z Setting output variable 'SqlDeploymentOutputFile' to 'D:\a\r1\a\GeneratedOutputFiles\.xml'
2024-01-06T21:28:23.8509958Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure SQL DacpacTask
```

Could the issue happens to the production database be related to assigning only the **Reader role** to the service principal on the resource group i am working on?
Is it necessary to have the **Contributor role** for these operations to be successful? I'm restricted here I can not get the Contributor role on the Resource Group.

Comment: Try adding a `UploadPipelineArtifact` task to get access to the generated log file which should be available under `$(SqlDeploymentOutputFile)`

Comment: I tried adding the Publish Pipeline Artifact in build pipeline and running the release pipeline manually, same issue appeared.

Comment: Are you aware that the `DeployReport` option doesn't do any actual changes, but generates a report of what changes it might do?

Comment: > DeployReport: Creates an XML report of the changes that would be made by a publish actions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You probably want to set `Publish` instead of `DeployReport`.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing for the heads-up, I was not aware about the differences between the DeployReport and Publish.

Comment: Now I changed the action to Publish and got the fresh error and the release pipeline got failed with the error below :`*** Could not deploy package.
Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15247, Level 16, State 13, Line 5 User does not have permission to perform this action.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [sys].[databases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 0;
    END
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException`

Comment: And also when I checked the Logs, ConnectionTimeout 120 and TargetTimeout:120 still happening.

Comment: What is important about those timeout values? They're for the deployment task, not your database settings.

Comment: You will need higher permission on the sql instance for the deployment to succeed. The permissions on the resource group are irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Publish` option instead of `DeployReport` to create/update the target database with dacpac file. Please check the argument [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=azuresqldb-current) for your reference.

[image]

> *** Could not deploy package. Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15247, Level 16, State 13, Line 5 User does not have permission to perform this action. Error SQL72045: Script execution error. ..

You are using `SQL server authentication`(username, password) to deploy the dacpac, and the error indicates the user doesn't have permission to update the DB. Please grant higher permission for the account, you can find the permission on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274793/permission-required-for-deploy-a-dacpac).

In addition, the Public network access on azure database is disabled by default. You can use `select network` and add the DevOps agent ip to the whitelhist, so that it can access the DB.

[image]

My yaml for your reference:

```
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest


steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2     # get agent ip and add it to DB white list.
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn3'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $ip =Invoke-RestMethod -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip"
      az sql server firewall-rule create -g "testRG" -s testserver1 -n myrule --start-ip-address $ip --end-ip-address $ip

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Azure SQL DacpacTask'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn3'
    AuthenticationType: 'server'
    ServerName: 'testserver1.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'wadedb1'
    SqlUsername: 'wade'
    SqlPassword: '$(password)'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: '**/wadedb1.dacpac'

- task: AzureCLI@2       # delete the agent ip on sql network
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn3'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $ip =Invoke-RestMethod -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip"
      az sql server firewall-rule delete -g "testRG" -s testserver1 -n myrule
```

[image]

Edit:

We can store the sql logins and passwords in keyvault and get the value in pipeline for Azure SQL DacpacTask.

Step1:
On the azure key valut, create the username and password secrets.
[image]

Step2: Grant `Key Vault Secrets User` for the service principal(from ARM service connection)
[image]

Step3: add `AzureKeyVault@2` task before your azure SQL Dacpac task to get the secrets value, and use `$(username)` and `$(password)` in the azure SQL Dacpac task for deployment.

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn3'
    KeyVaultName: 'wadekeyvalut7'
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: true

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Azure SQL DacpacTask'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn3'
    AuthenticationType: 'server'
    ServerName: 'testserver1.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'wadedb1'
    SqlUsername: '$(username)'
    SqlPassword: '$(password)'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: '**/wadedb1.dacpac'
```

[image]

Another option is to use 'servicePrincipal`as AuthenticationType in the Dacpac task, it will use the service principal to deploy instead of the sql user. But it needs to grant`SQL server admin` on azure portal for the service principal.
[image]

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn3'
    AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
    ServerName: 'testserver1.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'wadedb1'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: '**/wadedb1.dacpac'
```

Comment: Pipeline completed successfully by providing the db_owner permission on the PROD database. And also, it doesn't require adding the DevOps agent ip to the whitelhist.

Comment: I have one question, Can it be little granular on the permission on the PROD database(apart from Sysadmin or db_owner role)?

Comment: If your DevOps agent is able to access the Azure DB, you don't need to add the agent ip to the whitelist. To deploy the dacpac, the sql account should be members of the `sysadmin` or `serveradmin` fixed server roles, or by logins that are in the dbcreator fixed server role and have ALTER ANY LOGIN permissions, which is mentioned in official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/upgrade-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#Permissions). I'm afraid there is no little granular on the permission.

Comment: Okay, Can we use Azure Key Vault here for storing the sql login and passwords. Using Azure SQL DacpacTask for deploying the changes it's asking for SQL login and password details for connecting the database, is there any other way we can bypass this login and password that we are providing manually in the task and directly fetch these login and password from Azure Key Vault?

Comment: Yes, we can store the sql login and password in keyvalut, i will update the details in the reply, please check.

Comment: Hi @NileshPatel, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries.